# Simple model for friction in a pivot joint

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque, moment

Consider a pendulum that is attached to its pivot point using a hinge or ball bearing joint. What is a simple but reasonable approximation for modelling friction in that joint?

Background: I'm deriving the equations of motion for the cart and pole system, whereby an inverted pendulum attached to a cart is maintained in an upright position by an external force that pushes the cart left-right accordingly. In existing research papers I have looked at which model this system with friction, the pivot joint friction is given as a function of angular velocity. This doesn't seem to correspond with the notion of rotational friction being the result of dry/sliding Coulomb friction within the joint - which would result in hinge friction being a function of the force being applied at the joint (and the coefficient of friction).

Assume the system is within a vacuum (the cart friction term I have seen in the literature is modelled with dry sliding friction only, so I want to maintain consistency with that choice).

Comment: Is the shaft attached to the cart or the pole? I am trying to understand what is rotating in the hinge. Also if it is a ball bearing, you can ignore friction, or the equivalent friction coefficient is $<0.005$.

Comment: This is just the inverted pendulum rod falling left-right, and thus rotation of the pendulum around its hinge point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pendulum

Comment: A hinge has an inner part (the shaft) and an outer part (the hinge). Which part is attached to the cart and which to the pole? That makes a difference in how to model this in detail.

Comment: Currently, you have 2 degrees of freedom described. The horizontal position of the cart $x$ and the angle from vertical of the pole $\varphi$. Is this correct?

Comment: @ja72 Let's say the cart is attached to the shaft of the hinge, and the pendulum is attached to the outer part (the hinge). Yes there are two degrees of freedom in the system, the cart x position and the pole angle.

Comment: like [this](https://i.imgur.com/y6zj43Q.png) ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this equation for a friction torque in a spherical joint.

$$\tau_\mu=-\text{signum}( \dot{\theta})\,\mu\,|F_N|\,R$$

where

$\tau_\mu$ is the friction torque

$\mu$ friction coefficient

$F_N$ normal joint force

$R$ Joint radius

the "signum"  function is necessary, because the friction torque must operate always opposite to the angular velocity

**Example Pendulum**

[image]

for a pendulum is the normal force $F_N= m\,\left[\dot{\theta}^2+g\,\cos(\theta)\right]$

the equation of motions:

$$\ddot{\theta}+\frac{g}{L}\,\sin(\theta)-\tau_\mu=0$$

simulation results:

[image]

Comment: Note that if the pendulum is inverted then the centripetal force acting on the pendulum mass is vertically down, and therefore the corresponding reaction force at the joint is vertically up - acting to cancel out some of the force due to gravity. I.e. if the pendulm swings overhead with sufficient velocity then F_n can briefly become zero!

Comment: This example is simple pendulum, I don’t have the equation for inverted pendulum.